# Delete files in dir but exclude 1 subdir

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have a dir that is full of many htm reports that I keep around for 30 days and delete old ones via a cron, but there is one sub-dir I would like to keep longer.  So this is the line I made in the cron, but how do I tell it to leave one sub-dir alone.

```
5 0 * * * find /var/www -name "*.htm*" -type f -mtime +30 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Always figure out how to run any command on the command-line first and only once you've figured that out THEN add it to cron. Does that to-be-excluded directory name only exist at the 1 level of the directory tree where you want to exclude it or could the same name occur at different levels, sometimes to be excluded and others not?

Answer (score 2):

Use `-prune` to prevent going into a directory that matches some conditions.

```
find /var/www -type d -name 'excluded-directory' -prune -o -name "*.htm*" -type f -mtime +30 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to suggestion below, suggesting to use full path in `cron`.

Also to use `find` option `-delete` in-place of `-exec rm -f {} \;`. It is somewhat safer.

> ```
>  -delete
>         Delete found files and/or directories.  Always returns true.
>         This executes from the current working directory as find recurses
>         down the tree.  It will not attempt to delete a filename with a
>         "/" character in its pathname relative to "." for security
>         reasons.  Depth-first traversal processing is implied by this
>         option.  The -delete primary will fail to delete a directory if
>         it is not empty.  Following symlinks is incompatible with this
>         option.
> ```

```
5 0 * * * /usr/bin/find /var/www -type d -name 'excluded-directory' -prune -o -name "*.htm*" -type f -mtime +30 -delete
```